# Is there a URI scheme to open a predefined MUA reading a given email?

Tags: email, browser, html5, network-protocols

There are some well known URI schemes, for example:

- `file://` will tell the browser to do not perform an HTTP call and open a file instead. Example: `file:///C:/Users/alice/Desktop/README.txt`
- `mailto:` will open a MUA ready to compose a message, optionally with filled-in data. Example: `mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Hello&body=Hey,%20go!`

Question:

I need an URI scheme than when clicked instructs the MUA not to open the "composing window" (like `mailto:` does), but the "reading window". The MUA shouold open showing a specific email (for example identified by Message-Id).

Ideal example: `openmail:?Message-Id=1234@some-sender.example.com`

Is there such a scheme? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a URI scheme to open a predefined MUA reading a given email?

I don't think so.

The full list of URI schemes as defined by IANA is listed at [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Schemes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) and only includes `mailto:` for composing emails.

The nearest equivalent is probably `imap:` but without further investigation I'm not sure whether that will meet your specific needs.

See [RFC 2192: IMAP URL Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2192):

```
imap://<iserver>/<enc_mailbox>[uidvalidity]<iuid>[isection]
```

> refers to a specific message or message part.

See also [RFC 2060: Internet Message Access Protocol - Version 4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060)